# Finding the extreme points of $f(x,y,z)=\sin z(\cos y-\sin x)(\cos y\sin z+\cos x\sin y\cos z-\sin x\cos y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, optimization, vector-analysis

I want to find the extreme points of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ given by$$f(x,y,z)=\sin z(\cos y-\sin x)(\cos y\sin z+\cos x\sin y\cos z-\sin x\cos y)$$I know the function has extreme points because we can consider it as a function from $[0,2\pi ]^3$ ($\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic with period $2\pi$) and there we have extreme values from Weierstrass Theorem.
I've found the gradient of the function\begin{align*}f_x(x,y,z) & =\sin z \cos z(\sin x-\cos y)(\sin x\sin y+\cos x)-\cos x(\cos x\sin y\cos z-\sin x\cos z+\cos y\sin z) \\
f_y(x,y,z) & =\sin z((\cos y-\sin x)(\cos x\cos y\cos z-\sin y\sin z)-\sin y(\cos z(\cos x\sin y-\sin x)+\cos y\sin z)) \\
f_z(x,y,z) & =(\cos y-\sin x)\left (\cos ^2z(\cos x\sin y-\sin x)+\sin ^2z(\sin x-\cos x\sin y)+2\cos y\cos z\sin z\right )
\end{align*}and if I have a point $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\nabla f(x,y,z)=0$, I can use the Hessian Matrix to determine its nature, but I am not able to solve for $\nabla f(x,y,z)=0$.

Comment: There could be an infinite amount of extreme points of f. Are you looking for all of them? That’s a different question than just looking for one.  Or are you looking for the (unique) extreme value of f?

Comment: @CharlesF. There is effectively an incredible number of points in $[0,2\pi ]^3$ where the three partials are $0$ at the same time.

Comment: I know. For example, the curve z=0, cosy=sinx. My comment was to try to get the OP to improve this question. I just solved Df=0, so if that’s what is needed I will take my bounty. But the solution I found is obvious and says little about the extrema of f.

Comment: @CharlesF
I wanted to find the general solution (if it exists) of the gradient equation. For example, $\nabla f(x,y,z)=0\iff (x,y,z)\in \{(2n\pi ,(2n+1)\pi /2,n\pi ),((2n+1)\pi ,n\pi /2,(4n+1)\pi )\}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, I can finish the problem with the Hessian of $f$. If you did something like this, then your solution is more than welcome.

Comment: Thanks for giving me credit for the answer. Regarding your idea to finish the problem by checking H at all these points - it probably will be harder to do that than just directly search for the extreme values of f. Definiteness of H at a point where df is zero is a sufficient condition only for local optimality. This function is highly nonlinear, so I expect there to be a lot of local optima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to $\nabla f = 0$, but [I used my computer to guess a few](https://github.com/cfreundlich/stackexchange/blob/main/src/multivar.py):

```
    x      y      z
-----  -----  -----
0      pi/2   3pi/2
0      3pi/2  pi/2
pi/2   0      pi
pi/2   0      3pi/2
pi     pi/2   3pi/2
pi     3pi/2  pi/2
3pi/2  pi     0
3pi/2  pi     pi/2
```

All are mod $2 \pi$.

I think there are infinitely more critical points.  I also used my computer to find a few of those, but rather than printing them, I will include the scatter plot as a gif

[image: A few views of critical points for the gradient]

You can generate this plot with the provided code in [the GitHub link](https://github.com/cfreundlich/stackexchange/blob/main/src/multivar.py)